# Why is the $1/3$ Fractional Quantum Hall Effect the most robust?

Tags: quantum-hall-effect

As far as I know, the $1/3$ plateau is the most wide one, and the $1/5$ plateau is ok, while the $1/7$ filling does not correspond to a well-developed plateau.

So, why is the $1/3$ plateau the most robust one?

Comment: Where did you find data clearly showing the 1/5 and 1/7 plateaux?